# How to record sound with one button and automatically upload?

Tags: javascript, upload, record

Hi I use this HTML code which call JS which records speech and then saves it to my server. I have to click on "start", then click to "stop" recording and after recording click on "upload". I want to make it easier. So user will have to click on "start" and "stop" after that it will upload it automatically on server. Can you help me with this issue, because I am new and I don't know how to do that, Thanks.

```html
<html>
<body>   
  <button onclick="startRecording(this);">Start Recording</button>
  <button onclick="stopRecording(this);" disabled>Stop Recording</button>
  <button onclick="uploadIt(this);" id="uploadBtn" disabled>Upload Recording</button> 
  </body>
</html>
```

HTML calls JS which provides recording and upload:

```js
<script>
  var audio_context;
  var recorder;
  function startRecording(button) {
    recorder && recorder.clear(); 
    recorder && recorder.record(); // start recording 
    document.getElementById('uploadBtn').disabled = true; 
    button.disabled = true; //dont allow hit record button during recording 
    button.nextElementSibling.disabled = false;
  }

  function stopRecording(button) {    
    recorder && recorder.stop(); 
    button.disabled = true; 
    button.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
    
    createDownloadLink(); 
    document.getElementById('uploadBtn').disabled = false; //allow upload after recording
  }
  
  function uploadIt(button) { 
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {  // it calls function uploadAudioFromBlob from external file
      uploadAudioFromBlob(blob);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `uploadIt` in `stopRecording`?

Answer (score 0):

@holgac thanks, I put Upload function to stopRecording function and it works great:

```js
function stopRecording(button) {    
    recorder && recorder.stop(); 
    button.disabled = true; 
    button.previousElementSibling.disabled = false;
   
    recorder && recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {  
      uploadAudioFromBlob(blob);
    });
  }
```